# How to put .o and .exe files in a /build/ directory using makefile

Tags: makefile, g++

I'm struggling to find any information on makefiles which is truly beginner level.  Even the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178285/how-can-makefile-use-separate-directories-for-source-code-and-binaries), as asked, is presented using a load of symbols which I don't understand, like `$(CC) $(INC) $< $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)$@ $(LIBS)`.  That throws me off.

My makefile looks like this:

```
cpptest: main.o
    g++ -o cpptest main.o

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

clean:
    rm cpptest main.o
```

This is the full limit of what I know how to do with makefiles.  It works, but places the main.o and cpptest.exe files into the project root.

I want to place the main.o file and the cpptest.exe file into a /build/ directory.  However if I put `./build/` before every main.o and every cpptest, the object file appears in the project root and the exe file doesn't appear at all.

I'm building this thing using Sublime Text 3 on Windows, for what it's worth.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=makefile+tutorial

Comment: I looked at the first four results but the one which mentioned directories did so after introducing everything else first, so the example was hard to follow - and also the author seemed to get the macro / variable names for directories confused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly better solution would be as follows:  Notice, I'm doing a couple of funky things, but I'll explain along the way

```
all: build/cpptest

.PHONY: all

build:
    @echo "building directory $@"
    mkdir -p $@

build/cpptest: build/main.o | build
    @echo building $@
    g++ -o $@ $^

build/main.o: main.cpp | build
    @echo building $@
    g++ -o $@ -c $^

clean:
    @echo cleaning...
    rm -f build/*
```

Ok, lets look at the first and second targets:

```
all: build/cpptest

.PHONY: all
```

I created a default target called `all`.   This is a dummy target (it doesn't actually build a file called `all`), so I marked `all` as phony by making it a dependency on `.PHONY`.   (this basically tells make not to ignore the `all` rule, if a new file called `all` already exists).   `all` has no recipes, therefore it doesn't do anything except cause its dependencies to be created.   This might seem a bit convoluted, but it is standard practice in makefiles, as it gives you the freedom to organize the rules below in any order you find useful.

Third target:

```
build:
    @echo "building directory $@"
    mkdir -p $@
```

For the first target, build, this is the name of the directory you are creating.  `build` is the target, it has no dependencies, and has two recipe lines.   The first recipe line starts with a `@`.   This just means don't print the recipe before you run it.  If you didn't have this your output would look like:

```
 echo "building directory build"
 building directory build
```

Which is ugly.   The `@` only does that if it's at the start of the line.   You'll notice that later on the line you have `$@`.  This is different.   It is a variable that expands to the name of the target (`build` in this case).   It's a good habit to get into using this variable when appropriate, as it will simplify more complicated makefiles later on.   The second recipe of the `build` target creates the directory.

Fourth target:

```
build/cpptest: build/main.o | build
    @echo building $@
    g++ -o $@ $^
```

This says `build/cpptest` is dependent on `build/main.o` and `build` (i.e., don't start building these until the other two are done).   One big caviate: notice the `|` symbol before `build`.   This makes it an order-only dependency.  This means that if `build` directory already exists, and its timestamp is newer than `build/cpptest`, then don't consider `build/cpptest` to be out-of-date (don't rebuild it).   On the other hand, the other dependency, `build/main.o` is to the left of the `|` symbol.   This tells make that if `build/main.o` doesn't exist, OR if it is NEWER than `build/cpptest`, then make should rebuild `build/cpptest`.

The reason that we need the `|` (order only dependency) for `build` is that the directory's date is updated each time you add a new file.   Thus, `build` will always have a newer timestamp than `build/cpptest`.   This sort of falls under advanced makefile stuff, but it is the proper way to do it, so I thought I'd show it here.

As @Felix pointed out, order-only is not available in all versions of make (GNU make does support it though).

For the recipe, I used the `$@` variable and the `$^` variable.   `$^` represents all the non-order-only dependencies (i.e. `main.cpp` in this case).   These are expanded before the rule is run.

You can go a few steps further to make this truly proper (define an `$(objs)` variable for example, etc), which makes the makefile easier to maintain in the future, but this hopefully will give you a good start.

Comment: This is a good answer. Handling directories in a sensible way in Makefiles is indeed a complicated thing (you don't care for the timestamp of the directory, just have to ensure it's there), and *order only dependencies* are a good way to handle this. Still, AFAIR, they are not commonly supported in all flavours of `make`, so I suggest to add that it's the recommended thing for *GNU* make.

Comment: This isn't actually correct because main.o and cpptest are never created.  I fixed it by making 'build' the third rule, not the first, and also when using a .cpp to create the .o you need a -c argument before the -o.  Sorry but as it stands this is not a solution, can you accept my edits?

Comment: I have to say it was very informative otherwise and it was the introduction I needed.

Comment: Ahh, yes -- if you don't specify a target, make will run the first target it sees, and `build` would have been the first target.  The other part was me not checking my answer.  I'll update.