# Makefile to generate a binary file for each source file

Tags: makefile, build, automation, gnu-make

I have the following structure in my project.

- /

  - src/
  - bin/
  - Makefile

In src directory there will be multiple src files (each has a main function). I need to write makefile such that when I run
`make program1`
It should search for program1.c in src folder and compile the executable as program1* in bin folder.

I have came across this question [How can Makefile use separate directories for source code and binaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178285/how-can-makefile-use-separate-directories-for-source-code-and-binaries)
But, it seems that I need to manually enter all program names into PROG variable.
I just need to supply binary name with make and it should do the compilation for that respective src file?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a bit of experimentation with my Makefile. I finally got the solution for my problem.

**Current Build System**

```
   CC = gcc
   CFLAGS = -g -Wall
   SRC = ./src/
   BIN = ./bin/

   %: $(SRC)%.c
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(BIN)$@
   
   .PHONY: clean
   
   clean: 
       rm $(BIN)*
```