# Makefile Custom Pattern Matching

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am not entirely sure if what I am doing is possible in make, but I will give it a go.

So normally I can have a pattern matching rule like so

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c | $(OBJ_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

and if my understanding is correct, each target, like `obj/file.o` will be paired (depend on) with its respective prerequisite `src/file.c`.

Now, in my situation, I have a lot of nested directories under my src directory. So I was able to make/find a recursive command such that I can group all the source files together. An example looks like

```
SOURCES := [src/main.c src/dir1/a.c src/dir2/b.c]
```

and using the pattern substitution I was able to get a list of all the object files (without their nested directories) in the object directory like so

```
OBJECTS := [obj/main.o obj/a.o obj/b.o]
```

My problem is, I want a similar pattern rule like my first pattern where I can somehow say

```
obj/main.o   depends on    src/main.c
obj/a.o      depends on    src/dir1/a.c
...
```

and not have to write out all the targets and prerequisites explicitly.

Is this type of pattern matching possible in make?

This may be a duplicate, but I had an issue trying to articulate my problem while searching, so apologies in advance.

Comment: Is it okay if `src/dir1/a.c` -> `obj/dir1/a.o`? That's definitely possible with a substitution.

Comment: @Neil It wouldn't be my first pick but I think that could work. Any idea on how to accomplish that?

Comment: The order only prerequisite $(OBJ_DIR) will be for every single object file you build.  100 object files that 100 `[ -d $dir ] || mkdir $dir`. It's more efficient to have a single .PHONY rule to build your directories once.

Comment: Can you use vpath to find your src?

Comment: @AllanWind That might be a potential solution. Though I would need to add all the recursive subdirectories under `src` to the VPATH right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: If you haven't you might want to read this over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178285/how-can-makefile-use-separate-directories-for-source-code-and-binaries

Comment: Did you think about nested Makefiles? Or using a Makefile Generator like CMake? You might find some interesting information about Makefiles here: https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/

Comment: The rule you already have should do `src/dir1/a.c -> obj/dir1/a.o`, except for creating `obj/dir1/`.  And you can put that in the recipe: `mkdir -p $$(dirname $@)`.  That would even relieve you of need for the separate rule you have for `$(OBJ_DIR)`.

Comment: In *thegnumakebook* by *John Graham-Cumming* `rwildcard=$(foreach d,$(wildcard $1*),$(call rwildcard,$d/,$2) \
$(filter $(subst *,%,$2),$d))`, `c_srcs := $(call rwildcard, $(src), *.c)`, `c_objs := $(patsubst $(src)/%.c, $(build)/%.o, $(c_srcs))`.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question *Is this type of pattern matching possible in make?* is "no, that type of pattern matching is not possible".

In make patterns the stem (the part that matches the `%`) must be byte-for-byte identical in the target and prerequisite.

The only way to do what you want without writing a separate pattern rule for each subdirectory is to use vpath.  However you can easily do this as:

```
VPATH := $(sort $(dir $(SOURCES)))
```

which will set VPATH to all the directories of all the source files.  The sort also does a unique operation.